# library for searching value within nested dictionaries returning the value keys path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

Consider you have a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "keys": {
        "key1": {
            "param1": "value1",
            "param2": "value2"
        },
        "key2": {
            "param1": "param_value1",
            "param2": "param_value2"
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas of how to search a value which could be nested in some inner dict level and return the full path to the value.

I.E `search("param_value2")` will return  something like `keys/key2/param2`
I guess there are some libraries which provide this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

This works for the Dictionary in your question

```
dct = {
    "keys": {
        "key1": {
            "param1": "value1",
            "param2": "value2"
        },
        "key2": {
            "param1": "param_value1",
            "param2": "param_value2"
        }
    }
}


def search_value(searched_value):
    path = 'keys/'
    for key1,value1 in dct['keys'].items():
        for key2,value2 in dct['keys'][key1].items():
            if value2 == searched_value:
                path = 'keys/{0}/{1}'.format(key1,key2)
                break
    return path

print(search_value('param_value2'))
#>>>keys/key2/param2
```